# How to select coordinates that are within "N" km from reference coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates

I have two data frames, one with "Reference coordinates" from 26 sites, and another with many coordinates which are distribution points for different species. I want to know which species are found within a radius of 20 km from the coordinates of each site, so in the end, I am able to make a presence/absence matrix with the sites as rows, the species as columns and 0 for absence and 1 for presence.

Reference coordinates (26 Sites)

```
              Locality  Latitude Longitude
1              Daraina -13.20806  49.55667
2          Manongarivo -14.01483  48.37702
3          Tsaratanana -13.95306  48.86389
4             Marojejy -14.43734  49.68415
5    Tampolo (Masoala) -15.73177  49.97742
6 Sahamalaza (Masoala) -15.73333  50.21667
```

Distribution coordinates (2911 points)

```
                          Species      latS    longE
1         Beccariophoenix alfredii -20.20833 46.50111
2      Beccariophoenix fenestralis -19.01667 48.81361
3      Beccariophoenix fenestralis -18.97917 48.85444
4      Beccariophoenix fenestralis -18.96056 48.85583
5      Beccariophoenix fenestralis -18.95417 48.85583
6 Beccariophoenix madagascariensis -24.77667 47.14917
```

I have tried this:

```
library(gmt)

RefCoord <- read.csv("RefCoord.csv", header=TRUE)

SpeciesCoord <- read.csv("SpeciesCoord.csv", header=TRUE)

list = list2 = c()
for(j in 1:length(SearchCoord$latS)){
  for(jj in 1:length(RefCoord$Latitude)){

    if(RefCoord$Latitude[jj]==SearchCoord$latS[j]&RefCoord$Longitude[jj]==SearchCoord$longE[j]){
      distance = 0
    }else{distance = geodist(RefCoord$Latitude[jj],RefCoord$Longitude[jj],SearchCoord$latS[j],SearchCoord$longE[j],units="km")}

    if(distance<=20){
      list = c(list, j)
      list2 = c(list2, as.character(RefCoord$Locality[jj]))
    }
  }

} 

searchList <- list

refList <- as.character(list2)

searchList <- unique(searchList)

finalData <- SearchCoord[searchList,]
finalData$locality <- refList[searchList]
```

This code gives me wrong assignations for some reason. Does anyone have a better idea?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions about your objectives, because your code has an object `SearchCoord` which you don't provide, so I assumed that was `SpeciesCoord`.

With the `geodist` function, you can have a vector of coordinates for one of the reference points, making your double loop unnecessary. So for example, the following code gives the distance from the 1st locality to all of the species (you can do vice versa, so give all the localities and one species, but unfortunately I don't think you can give vectors for both):

```
geodist(RefCoord$Latitude[1],RefCoord$Longitude[1],SpeciesCoord$latS,SpeciesCoord$longE,units="km")
```

So you can calculate all of the distances into a list, then construct a matrix based off logical conditions with that list:

```
dist_list <- lapply(1:nrow(RefCoord), function(i) geodist(RefCoord$Latitude[i],RefCoord$Longitude[i],SpeciesCoord$latS,SpeciesCoord$longE,units="km"))

mat <- matrix(unlist(lapply(dist_list, function(val) as.numeric(val <= 600))), nrow = 6, ncol = 6, byrow = T)

colnames(mat) = SpeciesCoord$Species

rownames(mat) = RefCoord$Locality
```

For the data you provided, none of the species are within 20 km, so I changed it to 600 to show that the code should work

Comment: That worked on my data, thank you so much. What if instead of the presence-absence matrix I would like to get a data.frame with one column as the species name and another column with the site it belongs to (this done with the 30 km radius)? Any ideas? Thanks again.